# What is the single highest damage attack that can be made by one tenth level character with no assistance, support, or magic items?

Tags: dnd-5e, optimization

In a single attack (melee, ranged, or spell attacks all fine) what is the highest damage that a tenth level character on their own with no magic items can achieve?

Further caveats - no implausible circumstances beyond starting the situation hidden with the target unaware (thus qualifying for surprise), and having any number of preparation rounds as long as those preparation rounds do not invalidate stealth (such as casting a spell with verbal components).

For this situation, assume that feats are allowed, and all published classes and races, but not UA.

Comment: Damage to a single target? You may also want to limit the scope to one of melee, range, or spell.

Comment: @Jason_c_o: A single attack implies one attack roll. That's always against a single target, I think.  (Unless we're talking about taking the Attack action, possibly involving multiple attack rolls.)

Comment: When you say "implausible", do you mean that literally, or do you also want to rule out special cases like attacking a creature with some damage vulnerabilities?  e.g. Rakshasa vulnerable to piercing from magic weapons wielded by good-aligned characters, or Treants vulnerable to fire.  Those special cases are totally plausible, but not something you can do to most enemies. I guess probably it's interesting to answer for both cases, if optimizing for vulnerability would be less than optimal on ordinary targets. (You excluded magic items, so that only works if something makes it count as magic)

Answer (score 5):

## 201

- Rogue (Assassin) 5, attacks with surprise are criticals, +3d6 Sneak Attack = 36 [21]
- Paladin (any) 5 +3d8 scaled up Divine Smite = 48 [27]
- Cast as bonus action: Thunderous Smite +2d6 = 24 [14]
- Bugbear, +2d6 = 24 [14]
- Paladin Duelling Fighting Style +2
- Rapier 1d8 = 16 [9]
- Base Stat 16 +3
- Feat: Poisoner +2d8 = 32 [10]
- Feat: Magic Initiate for Booming Blade (caster level 10) +d8 = 16 [9]

**Total: 36 + 48 + 24 + 24 + 2 + 16 + 3 + 32 + 16 = 201**

To make it comparable with Dale M's answer, I am also using max rolls on the die, instead of average. The numbers in brackets give the expected damage instead, with assumed 55% save fail rate for the poison (we do not know the opponent's constitution).

Expected damage sums up to: 21 + 27 + 14 + 14 + 2 + 9 + 3 + 10 + 9 = 109.

Credit for the poisoner feat, for using a rapier to profit from Sneak attack, for Booming Blade, *and* for Thunderous Smite to save one class level all [go to Cezaryx](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/198309/what-is-the-single-highest-damage-attack-that-can-be-made-by-one-tenth-level-cha/198315#198315). Upvote his answer please!

Comment: Attacking a creature vulnerable to Radiant, such as a Skittering Horror (Ravnica) lets you double that part.  It's "plausible" that a 10th level character would be fighting a CR15 monster as part of a party, it's just a special case. It has 228HP so it's not overkill to do all this, thus plausible.  (It's not resistant to any of the other damage, including the non-magical piercing, which is a problem for some monsters with vulnerability to thunder damage, or a Rakshasa which is vulnerable to piecing from *magic* weapons by good-aligned characters but immune to non-magic physical attacks.)

Comment: Hmm, it seems that the only monsters vulnerable to radiant without also having resistance or immunity to non-magical physical are from specific settings, like the Guildmaster's Guide to Ravnica (a few monsters) or the Explorer's Guide to Wildemount (Gloomstalker).  Or Waterdeep: Dungeons of the Mad Mage has an Undead Bulette with vuln: radiant but immune to poison.

Comment: @PeterCordes The question was closed to allow the OP to clarify the conditions (i.e. one or several creatures to benefit feats that deal extra damage on several adjacent creatures, what kind of creature in regeards to resistances, vulnerabilities etc.) From them leaving out any such detail, my impression is that they are more interested how much damage the build can deal with a single attack "in a vacuum", i.e. witouth making any special assumptions about the target(s). We'll see.

Comment: Yeah, I already commented on the question before it was closed, to ask if they literally just meant "not implausible", or if they also meant "no special case targets".  Both questions are about equally interesting, IMO, since it's unlikely the answer would be a good build for cases where you aren't assumed to have hit (and crit).  Good point about the other possibilities like multiple targets for splash damage e.g. with Green Flame Blade or other cleaves from a single attack roll, or single Attack action.

Answer (score 5):

### You people have some rookie numbers: 191

what you need:

- bugbear race from monsters of the multiverse
- 8 levels of rogue assassin
- 2 levels of paladin
- at 4th level you take feat magic initiate for the booming blade
- at 8th level you take the poisoner feat

calculation(considering everything deals maximal damage, and you do crit):

- your rapier deals 16 damage
- your ability score modifier deals 3 damage(dex)
- your paladin's dueling deals 2 damage
- your sneak attack deals 42 damage
- booming blade gives you 16 damage
- bugbear gives you 24 damage from Surprise Attack
- your poison deals 32 damage on failed save(this damage is after CON save)
- your Divine Smite deals 32 damage
- your Thunderous Smite deals 24 damage
- Assassin gives you advantage on attack and an automatic crit if you are in first round of combat, you surprised your enemy and strike someone who hasn't acted yet. This does not increase damage per say, but makes this build way, way more reliable than other ones.

Score: 191
It would be higher if we assume you attack a fiend or undead(because of the smite), on the condition there actually exist a fiend or undead that is not immune to poison damage, so not here unfortunately.

This could be improved upon, by selecting a good spell from magic initiate, but I don't really checked this out.

Comment: I think you figured out what I was struggling with, how to get Sneak Attack in there, by giving up on the GWM for the melee damage which does not scale with critical.

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin I just assumed the critical, then almost all dice additions to damage are overweighting GWM, so I rolled with it. I was perplexed though why everyone takes half-orc, when bugbear have  2d6 on attack in first round of combat before your enemies. This is great for an assasin - and then I started writing all of this down.

Comment: I had Bugbear in there too, but Half Orc has Savage Attacker and Orcish Fury as a feat which adds 3d12 with Greataxe on crit. It does not work out better than 4d6 when you take a rapier which only is 3d8.

Comment: I think you need something else than booming blade though, that only deal damage if the target moves away willingly, wich we cannot assume

Comment: @GroodytheHobgoblin If the target  would move, then the additional d8 would have triggered, but that we cannot assume, true. The thing is, after 5th level booming blade improves, dealing an additional d8 thunder damage on hit, which is doubled by critical, as well as d8 to the damage after movement, which here is not improved.

Comment: Ah, right! Then it does work as you have it. Thanks for the explanation. I will steal it then for my build, but credit is of course yours. After I thew out the Fighter (Battlemaster) when I realized its not needed as I can just scale up smite by taking 3 more levels in Paladin, they are pretty similar now.

Comment: Can you explain how you got the 42 sneak attack damage? Lvl 8 Rogue has 4d6 sneak attack dice which should be 48 damage doubled? Am I missing something or was this an oversight?

Answer (score 2):

### I can get 63

**Paladin 5 / Battle Master Fighter 3 / Barbarian 1 / Sorcerer or Warlock or Wizard 1**

Greatsword (12) + 20 Str (5) + Divine Smite (16) + Duelling (2) + Rage (2) + Superiority Die (8) + Great Weapon Master (10) + Green Flame Blade (8) = 63 (109 on a critical hit).

Of course, the chance of rolling this is 1 in 49,502 (1 in 2,415,919,104 for the critical).

There are plenty of long duration spells that could add to this (e.g. Hex for a Warlock) but I have taken your prohibition on V component spells literally - none except for the one that makes the attack.

Comment: Some races can add damage, e.g. Aasimar (1/day wings) or Goblin (fury of the small) for +lvl damage on 1 hit (per turn or per short rest) would be an extra 10.  As other answers point out, with max rolls, Bugbear 2d6 is better, especially on a crit.